# Android AdWhirl & AdSense 3.1

Tags: android, adsense, adwhirl

AdSense (Google AdSense SDK 3.1) alone works fine in my app.

When I use AdWhirl  I see in my Log always:

```
:WARN/AdWhirl SDK(562): AdSense company name and app name are required parameters
```

How do I send this params right so also AdWhirl transfer it to 
AdSense?? (I didn't delete the params I used for ONLY ADSENSE.. so they are still there??)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the Solution :)

just simple add:

```
AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseAppName("Application Name");
AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseCompanyName("Developer Name");
AdWhirlAdapter.setGoogleAdSenseChannel("xxxxxxx");
AdWhirlTargeting.setKeywords("My keywords");
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole steps to use adwhirl please

Answer (score 1):

I think for this, you need to create an account on AdWhirl and then add your app to the account, enable adsense over there, provide your adsense api key on their web interface. They'll give you an AdWhirl api key. Then you can use adsense ads in your app using adwhirl api key.