# How to add GoogleAdd in my Android application

Tags: android, google-analytics, addition

I am here with one more question,
    I am creating one application individually.
Now i want to add `Google Adds` in my Application.

need help for this.
I am not getting from where i will get `ads:adUnitId="";`
i gone through `GoogleAddSense` but it requires website which i don't have :(.
can't i add the `google add` in my app if i don't have my website.
Please help me to add `google adds` in my app.
Please guide me how to implement adds in app.

Thanks
Mahaveer.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/zombie-run/ or see this [Que](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3543218/android-adwhirl-adsense-3-1)

Comment: Hi  gtumca-MAC thanks for quick reply but i dont want the code i just want to know is where i can get the "adUnitId". code i already have. i need my own "adUnitId".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be your AdMob publisher ID. You need to create an an AdMob account, then register an app [here](http://www.admob.com/my_sites/)  using "Add site/app". After that you can find your AdMob publisher ID under the new App details. Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks rfsbraz can you tell me please is it free or paid?? do we have to pay to use Google Adds?? i know its a fullish Question but i am illiterate of this please guid me. Thanks for this.

Comment: Yes, an AdMob account is free, and you can register as many apps as you want. There is an "Add funds" option, which is only required if you want to publish adds via AdMob.